# sklearn cross_validation ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm learning sklearn and trying to understand the cross validation method. I have loaded in my dataset which is a directory of subdirectories relating to each category, containing their corresponding files.

```
category_data = load_files('Datasets/Data/reviews_6_cat',
    shuffle=True, random_state=1, load_content = True,
    encoding='latin1', decode_error='strict')
```

I'm now trying to retrieve the cross validation score of this classifier:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=100)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, category_data.data, category_data.target, cv=5)
```

But i am getting the error "ValueError: could not convert string to float..."

I think it might be a problem with how my dataset is loaded in, as I can't retrieve the shape of the data:

```
category_data.data.shape
```

Gives me the error: "'list' object has no attribute 'shape'"

I've tried to convert it using numpy.array but it just gives me a 1D array which I don't think is right considering there are 6 categories.

**How can I load in my data so that it will work in the cross_validation method?**

Comment: did you check all items' type of your data? it seems you have str in your data

Comment: My dataset consists of strings, i'm trying to carry out text classification

Comment: I think you need to change string to onehot or cat

Comment: i've just realised my issue, i haven't converted it using the vectoriser! Silly mistake sorry

Comment: How then, one is supposed to run cross-validation with categorical values which are words?

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to convert data with TfidfVectorizer before passing into method:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()

vect_data = tfidf.fit_transform(category_data.data)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=100) 
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, vect_data, category_data.target, cv=10)

print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() / 2))
```

Comment: First, you are using older deprecated version of `cross_val_score`. Use `model_selection.cross_val_score` instead.

Comment: Second, this version of code may (will most probably) give you slightly higher results than what the actual model should give, because the cross-validation fold has data leakage from running TfidfVectorizer on whole data. You should first split the data and then vectorize them.